# Hashtable vs array of custom objects regarding iteration

Tags: powershell, hashtable, key-value-store

I frequently write lists of things and perform enumeration against them to perform some get/set.

I hate enumerating hashtables, since whenever I have to do it, I have to bend my mind backwards to work with `hashtable` objects.

```
$hashtablelistofitems = @{}

$hashtablelistofitems.add("i'm a key", "i'm a value")

foreach ($item in $hashtablelistofitems.keys) {
  $item
  $hashtablelistofitems.item($item)
}
```

Instead, I usually revert to using a single dimensional array of a custom object with two noteproperties.

```
$array = @()

$listofitems = "" | select key,value

$listofitems.key = "i'm a key"
$listofitems.value = "i'm a value"

$array += $listofitems

foreach ($item in $listofitems) {
  $item.key
  $item.value
}
```

Why should I be using a `hashtable` over this method?  Simply because it only guarantees a single value per key?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use a hashtable if you want to store a key value list and not create an *array* containing a custom object with two properties (key / values) for mainly two reasons:

1. You might want to pass your hashtable to a function that expect a hashtable.
2. Hashtable is a *built-in* PowerShell type which users are aware of. Your second approach is harder to read / maintain for other users.

**Note:** 
You can iterate over a hashtable almost the same way as your approach by calling the `GetEnumerator()` function:

```
foreach ($item in $listofitems.GetEnumerator()) {
  $item.key
  $item.value
}
```

---

Also, the hashtable comes with handy methods that you might want to use:

```
@{} | Get-Member | Where-Object MemberType -eq Method | Select Name
```

**Output:**

```
Name             
----             
Add              
Clear            
Clone            
Contains         
ContainsKey      
ContainsValue    
CopyTo           
Equals           
GetEnumerator    
GetHashCode      
GetObjectData    
GetType          
OnDeserialization
Remove           
ToString
```

Comment: I'm interested in hearing other people's input.  These are all good reasons.

Comment: Ahh hah!  It does!  can't accept the answer for another 3 minutes.

Comment: :-). But maybe someone can provide a better answer.

Comment: Maybe this is too elementary, but it wouldn't hurt to look over "help About_Hash_Tables" just to get the basic concept.

Answer (score 2):

This is nowhere near as useful as Martin's compendium, but it's useful enough.

It's an MSDN article about how to convert back and forth between Hashtables and PSCustomObjects.  [The article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/timid/2013/03/05/converting-pscustomobject-tofrom-hashtables/)